# jquery email extractor live from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

Okay so i have 2x textarea with different id's. I'm trying to extract the emails pasted into the first textarea and then displayed into the second textarea. I know my jquery work for extracting and sorting emails from text in a page, but i cant seem to get it to work with textarea's.

My code for the textarea's is as followed:

```
<textarea id="email-extractor" class="email-extractor-textarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="email-extracted" class="email-extractor-textarea"></textarea>
```

My code for the  is as followed:

```
<script>

function extractEmails (text)
{
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
}

function eliminateDuplicates (arr) {
    var i;
    var len=arr.length;
    var out=[];
    var obj={};

    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        obj[arr[i]]=0;
    }
    for (i in obj) {
        out.push(i);
    }
    return out;
}

var emailsFullList = [];

$('#email-extractor').keyup(function( index ) {
    var emails = extractEmails($(this).text());

    if (!emails) {
       $('#email-extracted').text('** No emails in comment');
    } else if (emails.length < 3) {
        emailsFullList = emailsFullList.concat(emails);
    } else {
        $('#email-extracted').text('** Ignoring comment, too many email addresses ('+emails.length+').');
    }
});

emailsFullList = eliminateDuplicates(emailsFullList);

$('#email-extracted').text(emailsFullList.join());

</script>
```

Comment: `.text()` should be `.val()` when working with textareas/inputs - though that doesn't seem to be the issue

Comment: Could you give an example of the expected inputs and outputs? You say that you are trying to "extract emails". Extract them from what/where?

Comment: i could paste this text into the first textarea: "jhsdgf sdkfhksdhf sjkhf skhdkf heretohelpphp@hotmail.com sdflksfj sdf karstenheretohelpphp@hotmail.com sdfds" The text i got in second box would then be like: heretohelpphp@hotmail.com, karstenheretohelpphp@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working the only thing is that you were not adding the text to the second text area correctly:

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/nkLvwtLa/

```
$('#email-extractor').keyup(function (index) {
    var emails = extractEmails($(this).val());
    console.log(emails);
    if (!emails) {
        $('#email-extracted').text('** No emails in comment');
    } else if (emails.length < 3) {
        var text = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
            text += emails[i] + ',';
        }
        $('#email-extracted').text(text);
    } else {
        $('#email-extracted').text('** Ignoring comment, too many email addresses (' + emails.length + ').');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I find the code working on jsfiddle but when i use the code on my website it doesnt work. http://truelads.com/email-extractor/ You have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
function extractEmails (text)
{
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
}

function eliminateDuplicates (arr) {
    var i;
    var len=arr.length;
    var out=[];
    var obj={};

    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        obj[arr[i]]=0;
    }
    for (i in obj) {
        out.push(i);
    }
    return out;
}

var emailsFullList = [];

$('#email-extractor').keyup(function( index ) {
    var emails = extractEmails($(this).val());

    if (!emails) {
       $('#email-extracted').val('** No emails in comment');
    } else if (emails.length < 3) {
        emailsFullList = emailsFullList.concat(emails);
    } else {
        $('#email-extracted').val('** Ignoring comment, too many email addresses ('+emails.length+').');
    }
    
    emailsFullList = eliminateDuplicates(emailsFullList);

    $('#email-extracted').val(emailsFullList.join());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="email-extractor" class="email-extractor-textarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="email-extracted" class="email-extractor-textarea"></textarea>
```

You need to move these lines...

```
emailsFullList = eliminateDuplicates(emailsFullList);

$('#email-extracted').text(emailsFullList.join());
```

into your `.keyup()` otherwise they are only run on page load. Also, when working with `textarea` I believe you should be using `.val()` rather than `.text()` to get/set the value

Comment: Thank you for your time. However i find your code working fine when running it here on stackoverflow i cannot find it to work on my website. http://truelads.com/email-extractor/

Comment: Well you are loading two different versions of jquery for a start. That could be causing an issue